# Bridge design pattern resulting in too many generics

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, bridge

I'm currently working on something for Minecraft, and I'm using the bridge pattern so my code can used with two separate server platforms, Sponge and Bukkit, with different (but somewhat similar) API's.

I have my core code, which depends only on abstractions of common things in Minecraft that I will need later on, such as players and items, as well as abstract factory and builder classes. The code for the specific server platforms will implement the factories and builders, and provide them as dependencies to the core code.

This has been working pretty well so far, but I'm running into an issue with abstractions that depend on each other. For example, I have adapters for Minecraft inventories and items that adapt from the server platform's item/inventory type, to my own abstract item/inventory type. Item and inventory objects will need to interact with each other, and since the core code doesn't know about the implementation, I've resorted to using generics. Here's some pseudocode:

```
interface Item<TBase> {
    TBase getBase();
}
interface Inventory<TItem extends Item<*>> {
    void addItem(TItem item);
}
```

The Item class adapts an item from the item type used by the server platform. The `addItem()` method implementations will use the `getBase()` method to add an instance of the server platform's item to an instance of the server platform's inventory. Overall, generics provide a solution to interaction between platform specific objects.

The problem I've been running into, however, is generics getting complicated as the size of the project increases. One reason is that classes that use items/inventories will require the same generics. For example, all players have an inventory:

```
interface Player<TItem extends Item<*>> {
    Inventory<TItem> getInventory();
    void giveItem(TItem item);
}
```

And something that uses a player needs to have generics, and so forth.

The second issue is that there are more interactions between instances than just these two, which could mean several generic parameters for an object, and therefore more generics on all the classes that use that object.

I suppose another solution would be not using generics at all, changing `getBase()` to return an `Object` type, and blindly cast, trusting that it's the correct type (which it will be).

I've put a ton of thought into this, and this is about the best I could come up with. I'm wondering if there are any other solutions that I'm missing, or any design patterns that might help with this problem.

If having the source would help, you can find it here:
https://github.com/BenWoodworth/FastCraft/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/net/benwoodworth/fastcraft

Comment: Why does `Player` need to have a generic related to `Item`? `Player`s aren't `Item`s.

Comment: I'm not sure how else to ensure that `getInventory()` provides an `Inventory` containing the correct implementation of `Item`.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: Well, isn't this a bridge pattern?

```
public interface InventoryHolder
{
    public void transfer(Player toPlayer, Item item);
}
```

then

```
public class Player implements InventoryHolder
{
    List<Item> items;
    public Item removeItem(Item item){
        return items.remove(items.indexOf(item));
    }
    public void addItem(Item item) {
        items.add(item);
    }
    public void transfer(Player toPlayer, Item item)
    {
        toPlayer.addItem(removeItem(item));
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Item {}
```

so

```
public class PlayGame
{
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new PlayGame().run();
    }
    private void run() {
        Player p1 = new Player();
        Player p2 = new Player();
        Item item = new Item();
        p1.addItem(item);
        // transfer
        p1.transfer(p2, item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the abstract dependency `ItemBuilder`, implemented by `SpongeItemBuilder` and `BukkitItemBuilder`, that is used to build items for the respective platforms (instead of `new Item()`). Let's say that the player's `Inventory` is the concrete implementation `BukkitInventory`, which adapts **Bukkit** inventory objects. If I build an `Item` with a `SpongeItemBuilder`, there's no type safety stopping me from trying to add the `Item` (which adapts a **Sponge** item) to the **Bukkit** inventory. The inventory from the Bukkit API being adapted can't accept an item from the **Sponge** API.

Comment: honestly this question is a design 'opinion' question and doesn't belong on SO. I would encourage you to step back and work on "version 2.0". A Person is an object, so I don't think it makes sense make it generic. It could be a base class, but generic classes tend to act on things, like a list stores things. So, you've gotten a little astray and need to reboot.

Comment: My thinking was that the abstract player carries items of a generic type, as lists contain objects of a generic type. In general, I'm asking because I want to see if there's a standard approach for bridging API's with interactions like this, so that I can rethink my impenetrable with a better approach in mind. A version 2.0 of sorts.

Comment: A Player delegates the holding the inventory to a different class, such as a list or set or your own custom inventory class. Even then, an Item sounds like base class. Generics would be for completely unrelated objects, a list of coins, a list of animals, a list of orders, so it seems like you're trying to use generics incorrectly. If you have different items with some things in common and some things specific to an item, you're describing a class hierarchy, i.e., polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

This is my current solution. If you see any room for improvement, by all means, share your insights. Here's some of my source code, simplified, and written in Kotlin.

dependencies:

```
// An abstract class, to be used by objects adapting
// native implementations. Provides an unwrap method,
// to unwrap the adapted object.
abstract class Adapter(protected val base: Any) {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun <T> unwrap() = base as T
}

// Inventory adapter, extends Adapter
abstract class InventoryAdapter(baseInventory: Any) : Adapter(baseInventory)

// Player adapter, extends Adapter
abstract class PlayerAdapter(basePlayer: Any) : Adapter(basePlayer) {
    abstract fun openInventory(inventory: InventoryAdapter)
}
```

Sponge implementation:

```
// Adapts Player (from the Sponge API)
class SpongePlayerAdapter(
        protected val basePlayer: Player
): PlayerAdapter(basePlayer) {

    override fun openInventory(inventory: InventoryAdapter) {
        // The unwrap<T>() method inferences T as Sponge's
        // Inventory type, from the openInventory parameter
        basePlayer.openInventory(inventory.unwrap())
    }
}
```

The need for generics has been removed, at the cost of type safety. `PlayerAdapter.openInventory()` can be called by passing in an `InventoryAdapter` object as a parameter. If the `PlayerAdapter` is a `SpongePlayerAdapter`, and the `InventoryAdapter` is a `SpongeInventoryAdapter`, then the `unwrap()` method will return a Sponge `Inventory`, and the inventory will be opened for the player as expected.

If a `BukkitInventoryAdapter` object were passed in, for example, a casting exception will be thrown at runtime, since the `unwrap()` method will try to cast a Bukkit `Inventory` to a Sponge `Inventory`. This isn't a big issue, and shouldn't cause errors as long as dependencies are injected correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The proper "solution" is to use a language that has a better type system than Java/Kotlin, unfortunately.

There's a type system feature exactly for this use case - called abstract type members or associated types or existential types (depending on the language).

This feature "hides" the generic parameter inside the concrete class, meaning that it does not bloat the generic parameter lists (the trade-off is that the type is hidden from the outside world when referred to via the base interface in the declarer/caller - it can only be accessed via the concrete class type itself).

As an example in Scala (refer to https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/abstract-type-members.html):

```scala
// Interfaces
trait ItemBridge {
  type TBase
  def getBase(): TBase
}

trait InventoryBridge {
  // Whoever is looking at this abstract interface, only knows that
  // this is *some* class implementing `ItemBridge`.
  // (hence the name "existential types")
  type TItemBridge <: ItemBridge
  def addItem(item: TItemBridge)
}

// Concrete implementations
class SpongeItemBridge extends ItemBridge {
   type TBase = SpongeItem
   ...
}

class SpongeInventoryBridge extends InventoryBridge {
   // ...but whenever referred to via this *concrete* class,
   // `TItemBridge` is known to be exactly `SpongeItemBridge`.
   // (and by extension, that `TItemBridge.TBase` is `SpongeItem`)
   type TItemBridge = SpongeItemBridge 

   val baseInventory: List[SpongeItem] = ... // This is the "base" inventory, however it's actually represented.

   // NOTE: The compiler knows `item.getBase()` returns a `SpongeItem` at this point.
   def addItem(item: SpongeItemBridge) = baseInventory.add(item.getBase())
}
```

(The interfaces have been renamed to have a `Bridge` suffix to make it a bit clearer)